# OpenCV delay in camera output on the screen

Tags: opencv, delay

I noticed a strange thing about OpenCV. I used one of the basic sample C programs delivered with OpenCV to show the camera output on the screen. I, however, see the output on the screen with a tiny delay compared to what the camera sees. So if I move my hand in front of the camera, it will show up on the screen with about 0.1 second delay. We are developing an application that is very sensitive to these delays. Is there a way to remove this delay such that the image transfer is instantaneous? I don't see tiny delay when I look at my camera output via Skype, for example.

Thank you very much!
P.

Comment: What is the final output resolution? And how does that compare to skypes resolution? Could you specify which sample as well? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Most probably you'll have to write your own, highly optimized, library to capture camera without delay. Simple drivers, like the one used in OpenCV have an inherent delay

Comment: The platform is Windows 7 64-bit. The output resolution is 640x480. The sample code is trivial. It's called camera.py and is in the samples directory for python. I don't know the quantitative difference between output speed from Skype vs OpenCV, but I can see just by looking at the video and moving my hand in front of it rapidly that when I output the video via imshow() in opencv, I get a delay of about 0.1 second but virtually no delay in Skype camera output. If the OpenCV drivers have inherent delay, then this is a problem with OpenCV and we'll have to change technology. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The openCV highgui display window is only meant for simple display of image processing results - it's not optimised for high performance or low latency.

You will have to write something to talk between the videoinput library and whatever display lib you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I store the video output to a file instead of outputting it to a screen, there will be no delay at all? Would that work, you think? I don't need to show it on the screen. I need to get the image processed virtually instantly. That's all that matters. Thanks!

Comment: The videoinput lib is pretty good, although it depends on what directshow filters are being used.  If you have relatively small images then a modern PC can do a lot of processing on each in 'real time' at low frame rates. If you need to do complex processing on a 1920x1080p image at 60fps it's trickier!

Comment: The camera is working in 640x480 px resolution and I am intentionally not doing any image processing. I am just reading the frames from the camera and displaying them on my screen using cv::imshow(). So if there is any processing done, it's only whatever is necessary to get the image displayed on the screen. Still there is that tiny delay. This delay doesn't happen with other software. I hope it's the issue with the highgui library that is not displaying the frames fast enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm - yes, once I turned off the highgui video output, the processing speed went significantly up and the FPS along with it. Now the app is capable of getting and processing frames at 80 FPS. One solution to similar problems that doesn't require writing a new video output library is to display only every, say, tenth frame of the video to save processing power.

Thanks

Comment: another factor that most people aren't aware of but causes big problems for us - the LCD screen's own internal electronics often has a delay of 3-4 frames (@60fps) giving a noticable lag if you are trying to do precise hand-eye tasks

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for sharing. It could be useful to know in the future.